# Exporting the cube with 6 faces (obj)

Tags: export, faces

I am a beginner with blender 3d and have a probably easy question.

I try to export the cube with 6 sides as a (obj) so I can import it into sweet home 3d, in SH3D I want to give each face a different color or texture ?

How can I do that ?

Comment: The ability to export as .obj is handled by an addon, which I don't think is enabled by default. Do you need help with that, or is your problem that you don't know how to assign colours in SH3D? The latter is likely off topic here, as it has nothing to do with blender itself.

Comment: You can assign different materials to different faces [this way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh), but don't expect OBJ to [export full fidelity material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) definitions.

Comment: The ability to export obj is active, the problem is that if I import the cube into SH3D that it is 1 obect, I need 6 faces - front-behind-left-right-top and bottom.

I know how to assign a color to an object in sh3d.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

Go to Edit mode -> Create 6 new colors -> Go to Edge - Split edge -> Deselect all (a) -> Select 1 face and give him 1 of the new Colors, repeat this for

each face.
Then -> File - Export - OBJ

Go to SH3D and import Furniture -> Import the cubes -> Customize furniture, now you can individually color each of the 6 faces.